# AWSToolkit for Eclipse --- Deploy Serverless Project Hangs at 10%

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, aws-toolkit

I'm going through the AWS Serverless Tutorial using the Eclipse plugin found here...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/serverless-projects.html

I simply used the HelloWorld blueprint and then selected to Deploy Serverless Project as the tutorial states. In the progress view I see..

```
Deploying Serverless template to AWS CloudFormation.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/
Deploying Serverless template to AWS CloudFormation.: Uploading Lambda function to S3...
```

At the bottom right I see 10%

But it never gets past this point. There's no error and opening the AWS CloudFormation in the AWS Explorer shows nothing.

I left it running over night. No luck. I've tried changing the JDK and ensured it was on Java 8 (OpenJDK8). No help there. I've tried installing the latest eclipse (2021-09) and reinstalling the AWSTookKit. Same issue.

In the AWS Explorer view in Eclipse I can see my EC2 instances, My S3 buckets (including the one created for the HelloWorld project), My DynamoDB instances I have created in the past. So I believe it is all hooked up properly in terms of credentials etc.

I see that it has packaged up the project into a zip file which appears to be 8.3MB in size. I assume this is what it's trying to send to the S3 but something isn't happy?

Would be great to have a view to see what it's getting stuck on so I can resolve the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I never did. I abandoned it as I couldn't get it going. Sorry, probably not the answer you want to hear. Wish I figured this one out.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Instead of running the latest Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers, Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0), Build id: 20220310-1457, I went and downloaded an older version:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen/2

Then I installed AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, and I was able to deploy the hello-world serverless Lambda without problems. I'll see if I can develop much more complex Lambda with this environment instead.

**Update**

In fact, the underlying problem is the error:

```
"Unable to complete transfer: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException"
```

Which I discovered when I try to drag&drop a file into an S3 bucket via AWS Explorer.

And the fix is mentioned here: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/issues/123.

Essentially, get a copy of the JAXB API JAR, e.g. jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar, into the Eclipse plugins folder, e.g. C:\Users\XXX\eclipse\jee-2022-03\eclipse\plugins. Then add a -dev option after -startup and --launch.library in the Eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
...
--launch.library
...
-dev
C:\Users\XXX\eclipse\jee-2022-03\eclipse\plugins\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
```

This fixed the problem for me.